# Unable to show data table output in conditional shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

Can someone helps me out?

I already tried to look at different tutorials, and previous questions/answers on Stack. But nothing helped me out.

I am creating a Shiny app, which would show a different output (data table) based on the input value.

Here is my code so far:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI for miles per gallon app ----
ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  # App title ----
  headerPanel("Clients per Township - Aggregation"),

  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
  sidebarPanel(
    helpText("Mean client's penetration (Number of Clients/Number of inhabitants) = 0.0089"),
    selectInput("Choice", "Do you want to have a list of townships with client's penetration above or under the mean?", c(" ", "Above","Under"))),

  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
    conditionalPanel(
      'input.Choice === "Above"',
      DT::dataTableOutput("more_table")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      'input.Choice === "Under"',
      DT::dataTableOutput("less_table")
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic to plot various variables against mpg ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  more_table = DT::renderDataTable({
    more_than_mean
  })


  less_table = DT::renderDataTable({
    less_than_mean
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The data tables more_than_mean, and less_than_mean were previously computed.

When I run the app, I don't get an error. BUT no output is showed. 
Can someone helps me out? I don't understand why none of the two tables are showed when I run the app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So after looking carefully again at my code, I found my (stupid) mistake.
I only forgot the "ouput$" before the name of the output tables!

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

# Define UI for miles per gallon app ----
ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  # App title ----
  headerPanel("Clients per Township - Aggregation"),

  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
  sidebarPanel(
    helpText("Mean client's penetration (Number of Clients/Number of inhabitants) = 0.0089"),
    selectInput("Choice", "Do you want to have a list of townships with client's penetration above or under the mean?", c(" ", "Above","Under"))),

  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
    conditionalPanel(
      'input.Choice === "Above"',
      DT::dataTableOutput("more_table")
    ),
    conditionalPanel(
      'input.Choice === "Under"',
      DT::dataTableOutput("less_table")
    )
  )
)


# Define server logic to plot various variables against mpg ----
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$more_table = DT::renderDataTable({
    more_than_mean
  })


  output$less_table = DT::renderDataTable({
    less_than_mean
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```